# ZF2 Doctrine - fieldset binding

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

I have read everything I can find but cannot seem to resolve my issue.  The problem is when editing the data binds to the form only from the base fieldset and does not pull in the data from the children (contact in this case).  So the form is filled with the data from ContactAddress but not Contact.  When I dump the query into Zend\Debug all the info is there but it is not making it to the form.  I hope someone can point out whatever silly mistake I am making.  Here are the parts of the code I think are relevant:

Controller:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id',0);
$form = new ContactsForm($em);

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('contactAddressId', 'contact')
         ->from('Application\Entity\ContactAddress', 'contactAddressId')
         ->where('contactAddressId = ' . $id)
         ->leftJoin('contactAddressId.contact', 'contact');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$contactAddress = $query->getResult();
$form->bind($contactAddress[0]);
return array('form' => $form);
```

ContactsForm:

```
parent::__construct('orders');
$this->setAttribute('method','post')
      ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false));
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'orderId',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'orderId',
        ),
    ));

    $contactAddressFieldset = new Fieldsets\ContactAddressFieldset($objectManager);
    $contactAddressFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
    $this->add($contactAddressFieldset);

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Add',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));
```

ContactsAddressFieldset:

```
parent::__construct('contactAddress');
    $hydrator = new AggregateHydrator();
    $hydrator->add(new     DoctrineHydrator($objectManager,'Application\Entity\ContactAddress'));
    $hydrator->add(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager,'Application\Entity\ContactAddressType'));
    $hydrator->add(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager,'Application\Entity\AddressType'));
    $this->setHydrator($hydrator);
    $this->setObject(new \Application\Entity\ContactAddress())
            ->setObject(new \Application\Entity\ContactAddressType())
            ->setObject(new \Application\Entity\AddressType());
    $this->setAttribute('method','post');

    $contactFieldSet = new ContactFieldset($objectManager);
    $this->add($contactFieldSet);


    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'contactAddressId',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'id' => 'contactAddressId',
        ),
    ));
```

etc etc

ContactsFieldset:

```
parent::__construct('contact');
    $hydrator = new AggregateHydrator();
    $hydrator->add(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager,'Application\Entity\Contact'));
    $hydrator->add(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager,'Application\Entity\ContactType'));
    $this->setHydrator($hydrator);
    $this->setObject(new \Application\Entity\Contact())
            ->setObject(new \Application\Entity\ContactType());

    $this->setAttribute('method','post');
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'contactId',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'id' => 'contactId',
        ),
    ));
```

Thanks for any help you can offer
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the to date version of the DoctrineModule, if you are using Zend Framework 2 with composer just make sure your composer.json file reads

"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "0.*",

and run php composer.phar self-update 
followed by
php composer.phar update 
This will install the latest version of the ORM module.

Also using the following link: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md

Will help you get started with using Doctrine and Zend Framework 2 Forms & Fieldsets.

Make sure to check your entities follow the similar pattern shown in the documentation, and when adding in the section for the OneToMany relationship has /** to begin with instead of the /*.

Also make sure that your form / fieldsets go in this order:

form->(OneToMany)Fieldset->(ManyToOne)Fieldset

Here I'm going to presume that a contact can have many addresses so your order of forms would be this:

ContactsForm -> ContactFieldset -> ContactAddressFieldset

Also when defining a ManyToOne fieldset try using a Form Collection, So in your ContactAddressFieldset you currently have the following:

```
$contactFieldSet = new ContactFieldset($objectManager);
$this->add($contactFieldSet);
```

Try changing it to this:

```
$contactFieldSet = new ContactFieldset($objectManager);
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'contact',
    'options' => array(
        'count' => 1,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_remove' => true,
        'target_element' => $contactFieldSet,
    )
));
```

The allow_add and allow_remove will (although add is set to true by default) will allow you to add and remove items from the form cleanly.

Hope this helps your situation.

Yamakiroshi

Comment: Nice answer. I'm looking for a solution to pretty much the same thing. Was wondering if it wouldn't be too much to ask you to write out an example where the 1-n and n-1 relations use a join table? My use case: Country#countryCurrency, CountryCurrency#countries, CountryCurrency#currencies, Currency#countryCurrency. Trying to figure out how to do both the 1-n and n-1 in a single form to create a Country and also create it's Currency entities.

Comment: Small addition to above question: CountryCurrency is also an entity as it contains a "primary" boolean to denote the Country's primary Currency.